# What is the fastest way of finding prime between n and 2n

Tags: algorithm, math

What is the fastest way of finding prime between `n` and `2n`,considering `n<2^32`.I'm talking about Bertrand's postulate

Comment: Seems like a math problem more than a programming one. Maybe try the math stackexchange site.

Comment: @csm_dev but i need a fast algorithm

Comment: What makes you think mathematicians don't create algorithms for these things? If you have an algorithm and you try to implement it in code and have a specific error or misunderstanding in that code then that would be a good question for stackoverflow.

Comment: @csm_dev thanks for your advice

Comment: Use a binary search on a pre-populated table of the primes from 2 to 2^33-1.

Comment: @AndrewMorton it will take a lot to populate an array of primes untill 2^33

Comment: @BrunoSnickers Yes, but then it will be very fast to find a prime between n and 2n, which is what you asked for. Perhaps you meant to ask a different question with more explanation of the problem?

Comment: linear search on the odd numbers together with a good primality test should be good. You could prepopulate a list of base-2 pseudoprimes less than 2^32 (something which is quite feasible -- just Google to find the complete list) and then just check if something is a base-2 probable prime (using a good modular exponentiation algorithm).

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks for your answer

Comment: As for populating array `2^33` is ~`10^10`. So number of primes will be ~`5*10^8` . You can split them into several files and do binary search.

Comment: I think he is talking about finding **a prime** not all the primes. So it would be enough to save the largest next prime which is smaller than double the previous prime.

Comment: For primality check of the largest numbers (2^33) you need to check against the primes below sqrt(2^33) which are 8952 and could be extracted with the sieve. Then you always double the prime and go backwards until you find one with the standard algo by checking if the number is dividable by any prime which squared is smaller than the number to check.

Comment: The number of primes that will have to be saved is smaller than 50.

Comment: @BrunoSnickers generating primes from 1 to n is very fast using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). Then just filter the result out

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc yes i will probably use that one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way would probably to pre-compute and store a 1-dimensional array of size `2^32`, where the value for index `n` is the desired prime number between `n` and `2n`. This would be an outrageous use of memory, of course, but it probably is fastest.

A slightly slower way that uses much less memory is to pre-compute and store a list of all "Bertrand primes", where the first element is the first
prime number and each element after the first is the greatest prime number
less than double the previous element. You can use a binary search of that list to quickly find the desired prime number. If you want `1 < n < 2^32` you need the last prime in that list to be above `2^32` to catch all such `n`. That would need a list of just 34 prime numbers, very doable. By the way, if you want to do this up to `2^64` you need only 66 prime numbers.

Here is Python 3.5 code to implement that algorithm. It uses a binary search function in the standard library. The list of Bertrand primes was found with another simple Python routine, though it is also available in [The Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A006992), sequence A006992.

```
from bisect import bisect_right

_bertrand_primes = [
             2,          3,          5,          7,         13,         23,
            43,         83,        163,        317,        631,       1259,
          2503,       5003,       9973,      19937,      39869,      79699,
        159389,     318751,     637499,    1274989,    2549951,    5099893,
      10199767,   20399531,   40799041,   81598067,  163196129,  326392249,
     652784471, 1305568919, 2611137817, 5222275627]

def prime_between_n_and_2n(n):
    """Find a prime number p such that n < p < 2n. The returned value
    will be the first 'Bertrand prime' <https://oeis.org/A006992>
    greater than n. n is limited to 1 < n < 2**32 but need not be an
    integer. Outside those limits, None is returned.
    """
    if 1 < n < 2**32:
        return _bertrand_primes[bisect_right(_bertrand_primes, n)]
```